# Recovering data from ext4 partition without any valid superblocks?

Tags: filesystems, dd, data-recovery

I recently screwed up a `dd` command and burned a 2.6GB installation file onto my `/home` hard drive. There were two partitions, a 930GB ext4 one and a 1.5GB luks-encrypted ext4 one. I used `testdisk` to restore both partitions, however, upon restoring, both partitions were in a damaged state, without any valid superblocks...

I have attempted to use `mkfs.ext4 -S /dev/sda1` to restore the partition, but this did recovered few files. I have tried to find the superblocks using the output of `mkfs.ext4 -n /dev/sda1` but none of the reported superblocks work. I can post the output of various commands as needed.

Comment: Was this gpt partitioned, so you have a backup partition table at the end of the drive? One advantage of gpt. Did you try deeper search with Testdisk? It sometimes finds full files.  I have used photorec (part of testdisk), but it only scans for files by type or extension, not full filename. And on smaller drive it took all night. You need another drive of at least size of partition to copy files into. And it finds deleted files also, so I had multiple copies of same file, not sure which was newer. Lots of compare & grep to see what was what. Did you try superblocks beyond 2.6GB?

Comment: The partitions are fine, but the files are not. I think the partition is offset by a few blocks, as `fdisk` is complaining about a 3072 byte offset. I will try to `dd` the partition to check.